# Alinhamento lateral de Divs

Tags: html, css, div

Tenho 2 divs no meu código, a primeira div é uma imagem, a segunda div é um formulário, quero colocar lado a lado os dois, e quando visto no mobile ela quebre, fique uma div em cima e a outra em baixo, como faço?

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border-color: #000;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 5em;
  resize: vertical;
}

.button {
  padding-left: 90px;
}

button {
  margin-left: .5em;
}


#main img{
 margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img width="240px" src="https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/google-chrome.png"/>
  <div class="center" id="form">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="name"></label>
       <input placeholder=" Nome Completo" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="mail"></label>
      <input placeholder=" E-mail" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="fone"></label>
        <input placeholder=" Telefone" type="fone" id="fone" name="user_fone">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloque o código para que a gente possa ajudar

Comment: Uma sugestão que funciona bem, é colocar as duas divs dentro de um <p> </p>, dessa forma eles podem se ajustar a página. Mas a forma mais correra mesmo é com bootstrap.

Comment: Tente, ao invés de usar a tag `<img />`, usar uma `<div />` com um `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

Há várias formas de fazer isso, mas no seu caso, creio que:

```
img{float:left;}
```

resolva...

Comment: Já usei o float, mas o problema é que quando eu aumento dimensão da tela pra testar, a imagem come o formulário ou vice versa.

Comment: Olha eu apenas adicionei o `img{float:left}` no topo do seu código e funcionou...

Answer (score 0):

Assim resolve, aqui aparece desalinhado porque o width da pagina é pequeno:

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
  display:left;
}
div + div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border-color: #000;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 5em;
  resize: vertical;
}

.button {
  padding-left: 90px;
}
button {
  margin-left: .5em;
}


#main img{
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img width="240px" src="https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/google-chrome.png"/>
  <div class="center" id="form">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="name"></label>
       <input placeholder=" Nome Completo" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="mail"></label>
      <input placeholder=" E-mail" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="fone"></label>
        <input placeholder=" Telefone" type="fone" id="fone" name="user_fone">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, usa mediaqueries... por exemplo

Para telas com tamanho maximo de 600px;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { img{float:right}}
```

se não vai acontecer isso mesmo, na tela grande ele vai ficar do lado, definindo uma média query esse estilo só vai afetar quando o tamanho atender

Para telas acima de 600px de largura e máximo de 900px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px) {}
```

E assim vai conforme sua necessidade, vale lembrar que talvez o ideal seja usar algum framework mobile first, talvez te poupe algum trabalho!